# jssc (serialPort.readBytes() ) with Arduino

Tags: java, serial-port, arduino

This is my Java code:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package jsscusbconnection;

import jssc.SerialPort;
import jssc.SerialPortEvent;
import jssc.SerialPortEventListener;
import jssc.SerialPortException;

/**
 *
 * @author Heshan
 */
public class JsscUsbConnection {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    static SerialPort serialPort;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        serialPort = new SerialPort("COM15");
        try {
            System.out.println("port open :" + serialPort.openPort());//Open port
            serialPort.setParams(SerialPort.BAUDRATE_9600,
                    SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                    SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                    SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

            int mask = SerialPort.MASK_RXCHAR + SerialPort.MASK_CTS + SerialPort.MASK_DSR;//Prepare mask
            serialPort.setEventsMask(mask);//Set mask
            serialPort.addEventListener(new SerialPortReader());//Add SerialPortEventListener
        } catch (SerialPortException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }

    static class SerialPortReader implements SerialPortEventListener {

        public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
            if (event.isRXCHAR()) {//If data is available
                //System.out.println(event.getEventValue());
                if (event.getEventValue() > 4) {//Check bytes count in the input buffer

                    //Read data, if 10 bytes available
                    try {
                        byte buffer[] = serialPort.readBytes(4);

                        System.out.println(buffer[0] + "  " + buffer[1] + "  " + buffer[2] + "  " + buffer[3]);
                    } catch (SerialPortException ex) {
                        System.out.println(ex);
                    }
                }
            } else if (event.isCTS()) {//If CTS line has changed state
                if (event.getEventValue() == 1) {//If line is ON
                    System.out.println("CTS - ON");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("CTS - OFF");
                }
            } else if (event.isDSR()) {///If DSR line has changed state
                if (event.getEventValue() == 1) {//If line is ON
                    System.out.println("DSR - ON");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("DSR - OFF");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Arduino code:

```
int k=0;

void setup(){
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
    Serial.println(67,BYTE);
    Serial.println(98,BYTE);
    Serial.println(34,BYTE);
    Serial.println(108,BYTE);
    Serial.flush();
}
```

This my output of Java code:

> 67  **13**  **10**  98
>   **13**  **10**  34  **13**
>   **10**  108  **13**  **10**
>    67  **13**  **10**  98

What are those bold values? I have no idea about these unknown values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

13 is a carriage return. 10 is a line feed. If you're dealing with serial I/O you should really know that. 9 is a tab. 12 is a form feed. Check the [ASCII table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

Answer (score 4):

10 and 13 bytes are \r\n symbols. The description of the `println()` function from http://arduino.cc:

> Prints data to the serial port as human-readable ASCII text followed by a carriage return >character (ASCII 13, or '\r') and a newline character (ASCII 10, or '\n'). This command takes >the same forms as Serial.print().

If you don't need these end line symbols use the [print()](http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/Print) function or the [write()](http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/Write) function for sending raw bytes.

Comment: thanx scream3r, it's work well. I have another problem. how can i send floating point numbers from arduino

Comment: The simplest way for that is to use print functions. The quote: `Serial.println(1.23456, 0) gives "1"
Serial.println(1.23456, 2) gives "1.23"
Serial.println(1.23456, 4) gives "1.2346"` For more info read this: http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/Print